# How to merge two columns together in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data:

```
1975,a,b
1976,b,c
1977,b,a
1977,a,b
1978,c,d
1979,e,f
1980,a,f
```

I want to have a two-column list of years and items, like so:

```
1975,a
1975,b
...
```

I have this code:

```
import pandas

# Set column names
colnames=['Date','Item1','Item2']

# read csv adding column names
data = pandas.read_csv('/Users/Simon/Dropbox/Work/Datasets/lagtest.csv', names=colnames)

# create a dataframe with info on dates for first column
datelist1 = data[['Date', 'Item1']]

# create a dataframe with info on dates for first column
datelist2 = data[['Date', 'Item2']]

bigdatelist = datelist1.append(datelist2)

print bigdatelist
```

But it gives me this:

```
   Date Item1 Item2
0  1975     a   NaN
1  1976     b   NaN
2  1977     b   NaN
3  1977     a   NaN
4  1978     c   NaN
5  1979     e   NaN
6  1980     a   NaN
0  1975   NaN     b
1  1976   NaN     c
2  1977   NaN     a
3  1977   NaN     b
4  1978   NaN     d
5  1979   NaN     f
6  1980   NaN     f
```

I want the line numbering to be continuous and for the two last columns to be merged into one. Any suggestions?

Comment: dataframes have `join` and `merge` methods. either of those will work.

Comment: thanks Paul! but using, for example `bigdatelist = pandas.merge(datelist1, datelist2, on='Date', how='right')` brings it back to being a correct 3 column dataframe. What I am looking for is for 'Item1' and 'Item2' to be merged into one column.

Comment: you could use an `apply` statement to select the values from the correct columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `pd.melt`.

Suppose you have this as your dataframe

```
>>> df
   Date item1 item2
0  1975     a     b
1  1976     b     c
2  1977     b     a
3  1977     a     b
4  1978     c     d
5  1979     e     f
6  1980     a     f

[7 rows x 3 columns]
```

Now use this:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars='year')['year','value']
```

to get what you need.

```
>>> pd.melt(df, id_vars='Date')[['Date','value']]
    Date value
0   1975     a
1   1976     b
2   1977     b
3   1977     a
4   1978     c
5   1979     e
6   1980     a
7   1975     b
8   1976     c
9   1977     a
10  1977     b
11  1978     d
12  1979     f
13  1980     f

[14 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks! The result you pasted is exactly what I need. However, when using

`bigdatelist = pandas.melt(bigdatelist, id_vars='Date')[['Date','value']]` 

I don't get 14 rows x 2 columns, but 28 x 2 with the same data as you, but also with NaN rows for all Dates. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the 'data' variable. That is right after you read_csv. Also i hope stack overflow has been useful to you -- be sure to accept the answers to your previous questions (including this one) if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! How do you mean that I could put the 'data' variable to use for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_index` and `stack`, preserves the order you intend

```
In [4227]: df.set_index('Date').stack().reset_index(name='value')[['Date', 'value']]
Out[4227]:
    Date value
0   1975     a
1   1975     b
2   1976     b
3   1976     c
4   1977     b
5   1977     a
6   1977     a
7   1977     b
8   1978     c
9   1978     d
10  1979     e
11  1979     f
12  1980     a
13  1980     f
```